# Create macro that is subset of other macro lists SAS

Tags: macros, sas

I have three lists of macros that have been created by a program, and I'm looking for an easy way to eliminate any dupes from the lists without looping back through the process that created them.

```
%let a=(1, 2, 3, 4);
%let b=(2, 8, 12);
%let c=(1, 3, 5, 7);
```

What I want is three new variables that have any overlap values eliminated, like this:

```
%let a_mod=(4);
%let b_mod=(8, 12);
%let c_mod=(5, 7);
```

I know there is probably a fairly straightforward way to do this in SAS.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of any approach to this could be considered "straightforward".  You could use an `except` operator in a `proc sql` query, but you'd have have to do some string parsing at the start to get your lists into datasets.  Do have a version of your three lists as datasets already, or do you have to start with the macro variable declarations you've provided?

Comment: I don't have them as datasets already.  I would have to build the datasets.  I think I'll just create the datasets before creating the macro lists, then use another sql to join them together, then subset by frequency and write into a macro list again.  Was hoping there would be a more elegant way, maybe by querying the macro lists themselves.  Doesn't look like that will work though....

Comment: Well, maybe someone smarter than me will come up with something brilliant.

Comment: @pyll, you point to the correct answer in your response: you wish they were datasets.  So, use datasets.  Don't use macro variables this way!  The lists should only come in the final use case.

Comment: Yes, I think you and Jeff are right.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Haven't played with it much, but sounds like you could use hashing for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Joe said in his comment is correct. Macro variables shouldn't be used to hold data; that's what datasets are for. Any solution that directly addresses the problem using macro functions and logic is likely to be fragile and error prone. Here is an approach that uses datasets. It's not entirely inelegant, at least in my opinion.

In your comment you mentioned that it's possible for you to store the values as datasets prior to creating the macro lists. That's great! I'll begin by assuming you have three datasets, `a`, `b`, and `c`, containing the values in a common variable called `v`.

First you want to join all three datasets.

```
proc sql;
    create table abc as
    select a.v as a,
        b.v as b,
        c.v as c
    from a
    full join b
    on a.v = b.v
    full join c
    on a.v = c.v
quit;
```

In the resulting dataset, here called `abc`, you have columns `a`, `b`, and `c`, each containing the values from the dataset of the same name. Since the datasets were full joined, all of the values are present. Then in any given row, if only one of `a`, `b`, and `c` are non-missing, you have a non-duplicate.

Now you can separate the values back out, omitting duplicates, akin to your `a_mod`, etc. macro lists.

```
data a_mod(keep=a) b_mod(keep=b) c_mod(keep=c);
    set abc;
    if n(a, b, c) = 1 then do;
        if a ne . then output a_mod;
        else if b ne . then output b_mod;
        else if c ne . then output c_mod;
    end;
run;
```

The `n()` function counts the number of non-missing arguments.

Now if you *need* lists again for whatever the final use may be, you can recreate them using the `into:` clause in `proc sql`, for example:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select a
    into: a_mod
    from a_mod
    separated by ', ';
quit;

%let a_mod = (&a_mod); /* To get the surrounding parentheses back */
```

While this will get you what you want in the case of just a few lists like in your question, it's good to note that a simple approach such as this one gets ugly and/or annoying if you have a ton of lists.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  This is very similar to what I ended up doing.  I didn't use the n() function though....but this would have helped simplify the code.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to hear you have a solution.